# Minimization of a Linear Function with Restrictions

Tags: statistics, optimization, matrix-calculus

I want to find the $\beta^*\in\mathbb R^k$ which minimizes $f(\beta) = (y - X\beta)'(y-X\beta) = \varepsilon'\varepsilon$ subject to the restriction $R\beta = r$. The standard approach would be to minimize the Lagrangian $$\mathcal L(\beta)  = f(\beta)- \lambda(R\beta - r).$$

Is this the only way which is practicable? Specifically, I was thinking about rewriting the equations:
$$\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{c} y \\ r \end{array}\right]}_{=\mathbf y} = \underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{c} X \\ R\end{array}\right]}_{=\mathbf X} + \underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{c} \varepsilon \\ 0\end{array}\right]}_{=\mathbf u}$$
 and then minimize $g(\beta) = \mathbf u'\mathbf u = (y - X\beta)'(y - X\beta) + 0 = f(\beta) + (R\beta - r)'(R\beta - r)$. Is this valid?

With the latter appraoch I get $$\begin{align*}\beta^* &= (X'X + R'R)^{-1}(X'y + R'r)\\&= b - (X'X)^{-1}R'(I + R(X'X)^{-1}R')^{-1}Rb + (X'X)^{-1}R'r - (X'X)^{-1}R'(I + R(X'X)^{-1}R')^{-1}R(X'X)^{-1}R'r\end{align*}$$ using the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula with $b = (X'X)^{-1}(X'y)$. However, the Lagrangian appraoch yields
$$\beta^* = b - (X'X)R'(R(X'X)^{-1}R')^{-1}(Rb - r).$$
Are both equations equivalent or is there a mistake somewhere?

Background: This is the deviation of the restricted least squares estimator of the linear model $y = X\beta + \varepsilon$.

Comment: they are not equivalent; your new objective balances between minimizing $f(\beta)$ and minimizing the error in the constraint $R\beta = r$, while the standard approach guarantees $R\beta = r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in the spirit of your approach.

The constraint is a linear equation
$$R\beta =r$$
so it has the *general* solution
$$\beta  = R^+r + Pu$$
where $R^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse, $\,P=(I-R^+R)\,$ is a projector into the nullspace of $R$, and $u$ is an arbitrary *unconstrained* vector. 

**NB:** The projector satisfies $\,RP=0\,$ and $\,PR^+=0$

The cost function is also a linear equation. Substitute the previous result and solve for the $u$ vector.
$$\eqalign{
y &= X\beta  \cr&= X(R^+r + Pu) \cr
XPu &= y- XR^+r \cr
u &= (XP)^+(y- XR^+r) \cr
}$$
Finally, substitute this back into the general solution to obtain the *constrained* solution.
$$\beta  = R^+r + P(XP)^+(y- XR^+r)$$

Comment: not exactely what I was hoping for but this solution is so neat! Very nice! Thank you for providing this answer!

Comment: @SydAmerikaner Exchanging the variables $(X,y)\Leftrightarrow(R,r)$ yields a dual problem. My solution to that problem looks a lot like your solution via the Lagrangian approach.